# reading an EEG dataset using EEGLAB

Tags: eeg, signal-detection

When I'm reading the documentation of importing events in EEGLAB from a file [here](http://sccn.ucsd.edu/wiki/A02:_Importing_Event_Epoch_Info) I have noticed that when we used a stimulus , we must know which time  we will apply it , since in the dataset file , you have to identify  of what times stimulus happen . 
 I don't know if my understanding is right or not , since i didn't  deal with EEG data practically (but in 2 weeks I will), but I was  reading a theoretical topics and papers on that.

 thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm unclear what this question means; it sounds to me like you're asking for theoretical papers on why you have to imported events have to have a timestamp, is that right?

Comment: @Krysta, my question is : when we do an ERP experiment do we need to know what times or period of times  that  stimulus  begin ?(i hope that's clear)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, yes, since ERP involves averaging over similar events, very accurate time-locking to stimulus onset is critical.  The idea of an ERP is that activity relevant to the stimulus will happen at a similar timepoint after similar stimuli--if you don't have an accurate time stamp (usually to the level of single milliseconds if not better), then the activity will be "smeared" across the time course.  For a good overview of ERPs, see the article [Event-related Potentials: An Overview](http://dx.doi.org/10.4103%2F0972-6748.57865)

Comment: then we cannot know if  a part of EEG signal is a P300 stimulus without knowing  the stimulus onset , which means that we know that part is a P300 signal from the time line , not from it's features , for example if the stimulus onset at t=1 s , them at t=1.3 s we expect a P300 signal , is this right ?

Comment: Basically yes, although the P3 best correlates with response timing, not stimulus timing, and there exist algorithms for identifying P3s based on the data, although not very well.